# How do use the same array of 10000 integers for two different programs?

Tags: java, arrays

For my program I have to compare the runtimes of sorting an array using bubble sort. The other uses parallel processing with bubble sort. The same array of 10000 integers(random integers) must be used. My program keeps creating a new array.

I tried creating an array class with an static array and a static variable called k. I have it so that when each program makes an array object, it calls an static instance method to populate the array. The method has a for-loop nested within an if-statement. After first calling the method, the variable k increments. Once the method is called once more, the if statement checks if the method was called before. If yes, the for-loop to repopulate the array is skipped and the program simply return the array with the variables it is already populated with.

```
public class Array
{
    static int i;
    static int[] array = new int[10000];
    static int k;

    Array()
    {
       populate();
    }
    public static int[] populate()
    {
        if(k==0)
        {
            for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            {
                array[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 10000);  
            }
        }
      return array;      
    }
 }
```

I am supposed to be getting the same array with every run. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Why don't just copy an array with `Arrays.copyOf()` and pass it to a new thread?

Comment: Instead of `Math.random()`, you should initialize your own `Random` object with a specific seed so that you generate the same random numbers every time.

Comment: Save it to a .txt file.

Comment: Do you really mean two separate programs?  If so, then @JacobG.'s advice is simplest - instead of trying to 'share' the data (which can only be done by writing it to external storage, since the program memory does not exist between runs) it is simpler to write code which is repeatable.

Comment: Thanks guys. The Random object seems to be doing the trick :)